# Record From Database not Binding to Select Control in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an edit form with input fields and select controls. These controls are supposed to be populated with a record from database as you know it. The input fields have their respective data in it but the select controls do not.

This is one of my Select controls

```
<select id="taxAuthorityId" name="taxAuthorityId" [(ngModel)]="tax.taxAuthorityId" class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let b of taxAuthorities" value={{b.Id}}>{{b.name}}</option>
</select>
```

`tax` is an object with data which I confirmed by logging it in the console and it returns all the fields as expected including `taxAuthorityId` in this case. But it is not selected on the control. How can I get this to work for all my selected controls?

**TypeScript code for the Tax Object**

```
show(id: number): void {
    this._taxService.get(id)
      .subscribe((result: TaxDto) => {
          this.tax = result;
          console.log(this.tax);
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally value attribute value gets stringified, so when you're put `b.id` in it it becomes `'1'` instead of `1`. So when it comes to pre-select value 1 === '1' this expression doesn't get satisfied . Change `value` to `[ngValue]="b.Id"` will help to preserve value type.

```
<select id="taxAuthorityId" name="taxAuthorityId" 
   [(ngModel)]="tax.taxAuthorityId" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let b of taxAuthorities" 
        [ngValue]="b.Id">
          {{b.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DnxQiV2a3pTw018NcXf6?p=preview)

Comment: Hi. It threw a parser error in the console. The whole application didn't run

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha can you please tell me what is error?

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. I replaced {{}} with " " as it is in your answer. But it still did not display the selected value.

Comment: My fault again. The property was wrong. It was supposed to "b.id" instead of "b.Id". Your answer is correct. Many thanks. I don't believe I spent two nights on this.